# How to print a large Photoshop file (.psb)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-production, file-format, eps

I want to print a large document, a PSB file of 3.21 Go. But I want that document to be 270x305 cm and 300 dpi. The problem is that my printer want a file in the EPS format and that Photoshop don't allow me to save my PSB file to an EPS format.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Most print providers requesting EPS files want **vector** files. You simply can not do that with Photoshop. However, in many cases you *should* be able to export/save a 300ppi TIFF file for reproduction - unless, of course, the reproduction method requires a vector file.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So, I have exported my PSB file to a TIF file and then I imported it in Illustrator. Because of that I was able to export it to an EPS file. The problem is that I can't open the EPS file in Photoshop. Is it normal?

Comment: I **highly** doubt the print shop merely wants a file with the suffix .eps. Generally they want **vector** files when requesting an EPS. Opening a Tiff in Illustrator and saving it as an EPS *does not* create a vector file. You need to ask the print house *specifically* about what they need. Do they need vector or do they need an eps even if it's a raster eps.

Comment: That is a crazy large image. 81000 x 91500 px. I can't understand why this is necessary. Remember that the 300 ppi ideal is for images which are to be viewed at normal reading distance. About 30 cm. Large prints are often viewed from a longer distance and the resolution needed follows the viewing distance linearly. It would be interesting to see how your image looks. If it could be remade in vector graphics you would have less problems.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Scott, I will try to ask him what he needs specifically, thanks for your remarks. Wolff, I know, it's kinda crazy... It's a photo for an art exhibition. In that case people will be able to be at a 30 cm distance of the print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time someone wants to print a file at 300 PPI on sizes beyond 1 m, I really wonder if they needed it. Well, in reality, I know they do not.

Let me explain some things about the 300 PPI "myth".

---

Let me start with a flat sheeted offset, for example, a movie poster of good quality of course. On the prepress process, these images need to be transformed from pixels to lines, at the end we will have a print of about 150 LPI. This is the normal lineature you see in a fashion magazine, depending on the print quality this can be great and detailed images. A magazine is intended to be viewed at 30 cm.

From a mathematical point of view, we do not even need 300PPI, but the Lineature multiplied by the square root of two. For 150 LPI this will be 150 x 1.414 = 212 PPI.

Of course, the maximum size of a flat sheeted offset machine is around 1 m, let's say 1.2ish on really big machines.

The size you need is obviously a digital print.

On a digital print, this transformation does not take place (only in really rare cases) this means that you will have more final resolution with a 200PPI file than a 150LPI print.

You can even use 150 PPI and you can barely see an isolated pixel at 30-50cm.

---

A really expensive camera of $50,000 can have a photo of 100Mpx. This kind of cameras are to make big prints from people with egocentric issues :o) let's say a Hollywood actor that wants a self-portrait of about an entire wall.

Remember the numbers: 100Mpx... you want a file of 36,023 x 31,889 which is about 1,149 Megapixels.

---

It is ok if it is an awesome panorama of the city and you want to see the faces of the townsfolk. But really, 150 PPI will be 1/4 the image and still will be an excellent print.

---

A Magazine (let's say 30cm height) is meant to be viewed at 30cm. A wall-sized image does not. It is meant to be viewed at, let's say 3 m. This means that the same image that you use on a 30cm magazine can be used on a wall.

---

A printer provider will probably transform your image. No one wants to process a file of unnecessary size.

---

One more thing I need to say is that probably you did your project in the wrong program.

As already commented, an EPS file is asked when you have vector elements, so Ps is not the right tool.

---

One last thing. **Do not trust me. Make some test files with the same provider. On the small size of A4-Letter size print. Make one file at 300PPI, one at 250, 200, 150, 100PPI and make a decision.**

Comment: Thanks for all your advice, it is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem once.  We had some rather big files that we created as PSBs for a "car wrap".  In our case, I believe we ended up having to size the file down small enough to save as a PSD.

Then we ended up doing an Import to Illustrator and used the Image Trace.  The design was simple enough in our case that we were able to make it work that way.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But in my case it wouldn't work because it's not a simple design, it's a rather complex photo...

Comment: Got it!.  I'd still recommend giving it a shot.  It's a pretty quick process and with the latest versions of CC -- I've seen some really incredible results (even with images that are much more complex).  Of course, you can also source other print agencies that work with PSB files... A lot depends on where you are located.

Comment: At the end we decided to use a file with a lower dpi. But thank you for your advice, I will think of it if I find myself in a similar situation next time!